# how to set multiple conditions in if else statement php

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<html>
<head>
<title> GRADE DETAILS </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$myname=$_GET ['myname'];
$mygrade=$_GET ['mygrade'];

if(($myname=='@' or $myname=='!'))
{
    echo "Special character not allowed.";
}

else if($myname==" ")
{
    echo "Please enter your name";

}


else
{
    switch($mygrade)
{
case "";
echo "you did not enter grade";
break;

case A;
echo "Increment 30% of basic salary";
break;

case B;
echo "Increment 10% of basic salary";
break;

default;
echo"Wrong Grade";
break;
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to set multiple conditions at my if else statement..i try many way, but still didn't work...i hope someone can help me ..nothing to do with my Switch Case, but the problem only at IF ELSE..PLS HELP.Thanks.

Comment: Is this a plain PHP? no framework?

Comment: im using HTML framework, but i didnt send the HTML code here..

Answer (score 1):

It's basically OK, but you need to replace the semicolons after the "CASE" statements with colons, and second put the text strings (A, B etc.) into quotes:

```
switch($mygrade) {
    case "":
        echo "you did not enter grade";
    break;

    case "A":
        echo "Increment 30% of basic salary";
    break;

    case "B":
        echo "Increment 10% of basic salary";
    break;

    default:
        echo "Wrong Grade";
    break;
}
```

Comment: i change it as u said..but nothing change with my php.. only my if else have a problem when i try to set multiple conditions.. (eg: if user insert special character like "!,@,#" ..then a "Special character not allowed." will come out..but it didnt work.. :(

Comment: Do you want to check, if the name contains special characters? You are checking if the name is "@", but if a name is "thomas @", then it won't work. Check Louie Miranda's answer, it is good i think.

Comment: ouh ya..that what i wanted.. if user insert any symbol like d@niel, then the program will run the 1st if else statement. is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, see Louie Miranda's answer above: `$invalid = array("@", "!"); if (in_array($myname, $invalid)) { echo 'Special character not allowed.'; }`

Comment: is there any way other than using array? because i'm still learning php..im not good at array yet.

Comment: This code: `if (preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/', '', $myname)=='')` will return TRUE, if the name only contains A-Z, and FALSE if there are invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

You where missing some quotes, `A` and `B` are interpreted as constants

```
<?php
$myname= trim($_GET ['myname']);
$mygrade= trim($_GET ['mygrade']);

if(strstr('@',$myname) or strstr('!',$myname) )
{
    echo "Special character not allowed.";
}

else if(empty($myname))
{
    echo "Please enter your name";

}


else
{
    switch($mygrade)
{
case "":
echo "you did not enter grade";
break;

case 'A':
echo "Increment 30% of basic salary";
break;

case 'B':
echo "Increment 10% of basic salary";
break;

default:
echo"Wrong Grade";
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a plain PHP? I have my answers below. But, I am not recommending that you continue with this. You can search for other class or framework that can help you on the validation. This might be prone on injection as well.

To answer your question: (Basically)

```
$invalid = array("@", "!");
if (in_array($myname, $invalid)) {
    echo 'Special character not allowed.';
}

if (empty($myname)) {
    echo "Please enter your name";
}

if (!empty($mygrade)) {
    switch($mygrade) {
       case "":
        echo "you did not enter grade";
        break;

    case "A":
        echo "Increment 30% of basic salary";
        break;

    case "B":
        echo "Increment 10% of basic salary";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Wrong Grade";
        break;
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Grade was empty';
}
```